# Swift: Subscript with Ranges error

Tags: swift, range

I am playing with subscripts in Swift, following the book "Mastering Swift 2":

```
// SUBSCRIPTS WITH RANGES

struct MathTableWithRanges{
    var num : Int

    subscript(index : Int)->Int{
         return num * index
    }

    subscript(aRange: Range<Int>)->[Int]{

       var retArray : [Int] = []
       for i in aRange{
           retArray.append(self[i])
       }
       return retArray
    }
}

// Test code

var table = MathTable(num: 5)
var myRange : Range<Int> = 2...5
print(table[myRange])
```

**Expected output**: 10,15, 20, 25

**Error**: Cannot convert value of type Range to expected argument type Int

*Note*: If I hard code the Range:

```
print(table[2...5])
```

I get a different **error**:
Binary operator '...' cannot be applied to two Int operands

Comment: Your code works for me, no errors when using the correct class name. ([screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOwIY_SP5VFAVqsplnj32XCzAC_gwood_No)). Check your Xcode version number, it should be at least 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't got the book you are using, but this line:

```
var table = MathTable(num: 5)
```

Should probably be this:

```
var table = MathTableWithRanges(num: 5)
```

Comment: ooooops!!!!! Can't believe it! I have several structures in my code and I was pointing to the wrong one as you correctly found out!!! Thanks